# Receive image in Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

The following code is for a python server that can receive a string.

```
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 8001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    length = conn.recv(1027)
    data = conn.recv(int(length))
    import StringIO
    buff = StringIO.StringIO()
    buff.write(data)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
    conn.send('Thanks')  # echo
    get_result(buff)    
conn.close()
```

Can anyone help me to edit this code or create a similar one to be able to receive images instead of string?

Answer (score 5):

First, your code actually *can't* receive a string. [Sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html).

This line:

```
length = conn.recv(1027)
```

… will receive anywhere from 1 to 1027 bytes.

You need to loop around each `recv` and accumulate a buffer, like this:

```
def recvall(conn, length):
    buf = b''
    while len(buf) < length:
        data = conn.recv(length - len(buf))
        if not data:
            return data
        buf += data
    return buf
```

Now you can make it work like this:

```
while True:
    length = recvall(conn, 1027)
    if not length: break
    data = recvall(conn, int(length))
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
    conn.send('Thanks')  # echo
```

---

You can use `StringIO` or other techniques instead of concatenation for performance reasons, but I left that out because it's simpler and more concise this way, and understanding the code is more important than performance.

Meanwhile, it's worth pointing out that 1027 bytes is a ridiculous huge amount of space to use for a length prefix. Also, your sending code has to make sure to actually send 1027 bytes, no matter what. And your responses have to always be exactly 6 bytes long for this to work.

```
def send_string(conn, msg):
    conn.sendall(str(len(msg)).ljust(1027))
    conn.sendall(msg)
    response = recvall(conn, 6)
    return response
```

But at least now it is workable.

---

So, why did you *think* it worked?

TCP is a stream of bytes, not a stream of messages. There's no guarantee that a single `send` from one side will match up with the next `recv` on the other side. However, when you're running both sides on the same computer, sending relatively small buffers, and aren't loading the computer down too badly, they will often happen to match up 1-to-1. After all, each time you call `recv`, the other side has probably only had time to `send` one message, which is sitting in the OS's buffers all by itself, so the OS just gives you the whole thing. So, your code will appear to work in initial testing.

But if you send the message through a router to another computer, or if you wait long enough for the other side to make multiple `send` calls, or if your message is too big to fit into a single buffer, or if you just get unlucky, there could be 2-1/2 messages waiting in the buffer, and the OS will give you the whole 2-1/2 messages. And then your next `recv` will get the leftover 1/2 message.

---

So, how do you make this work for images? Well, it depends on what you mean by that.

You can read an image file into memory as a sequence of bytes, and call `send_string` on that sequence, and it will work fine. Then the other side can save that file, or interpret it as an image file and display it, or whatever it wants.

Alternatively, you can use something like `PIL` to parse and decompress an image file into a bitmap. Then, you encode the header data (width, height, pixel format, etc.) in some way (e.g., `pickle` it), `send_string` the header, then `send_string` the bitmap.

If the header has a fixed size (e.g., it's a simple structure that you can serialize with `struct.pack`), and contains enough information for the other side to figure out the length of the bitmap in bytes, you don't need to `send_string` each one; just use `conn.sendall(serialized_header)` then `conn.sendall(bitmap)`.